# "Update Failed: An unknown error occurred" while trying to add VPC network for GCP Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I am trying to connect to my Google Cloud Postgres instance running in Cloud SQL using Private IP, following the tutorials listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip).

Since the docs require you to set up a VPC network to connect via Private IP, I created one following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc).

After setting up the VPC network and enabling Private IP connections to the PostGres instance, I went to the 'connections' page for the PostGres instance and selected the network that had just been created.

After saving my changes, a dialog box popped up saying `"Update failed: An unknown error occurred"`.

There is no mention of the problem in the activity panel logs - they just say that a request to add peering succeeded. I am new to this and am not sure if this is related or not.

Some of the fixes I have attempted:

1. Adding an network admin role for my account (even though I am already the project owner).
2. Checking to make sure that the Service Networking API is enabled for the project (it is enabled).
3. Disabling and Reenabling the Service Networking APO.
4. Creating another Cloud Postgres instance with Private IP enabled and then trying to connect to the network. 
   This fails, which seems to indicate that the problem is with the network rather than the database itself.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clarify your question. On one hand, you mention VPC, then Peering. Show how the networks are configured. If you have peered two VPCs, show the peering connections for both VPCs. Is your Postgres instance GCE or Cloud SQL? Lots of details missing to help you. Note: Don't add comments, edit your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Just edited per your comment.